# Excel selecting a number of cells below selected cell shortcut options

Tags: excel

In Excel, I would like to select a cell and then copy the contents to n number of cells below.  Instead of using the "fill" drag option since the number of rows will be fairly large and require scrolling and then stopping at the correct cell I was looking for other options.

I am currently doing the the following:

In excel I select a cell and then on the top left corner it shows the cell (i.e. A1).  Then to select the number of cells below it, I modify the top left box to a range such as A1:A10 which selects the range of cells. See attached image.  I then use the shortcut key "Ctrl-D" which copies the first cell to the other cells.

Is there a way instead of mentally calculating the ending cell number, I can do something that effectively works "A1 + 10" in this box to select 10 cells below to select the A1:A10 range?

[image]

Comment: you write some vba that uses an input box to ask the number of cells to copy down then does the action based on the cell selected.  Then you tie it to a shortcut key and viola you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way? Enter your formula in cell 1. Enter the number of copies (including the original) you want of it in the cell below it. Double-click on the number you entered and the formula is filled down.

To try, install the procedure below in the code module of the worksheet on which you want the action. (That's a module Excel set up when you created the sheet. Don't install the code in a standard code module that you have to insert yourself.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Const TriggerClm    As String = "A"
    Dim R               As Long
    
    With Target
        If (.Column = Columns(TriggerClm).Column) And (.Row > 1) Then
            R = Val(.Value)
            If R Then
                With .Offset(-1)
                    If .HasFormula Then
                        .Resize(R).FillDown
                        .Select
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You may wish or have to tweak the code. For example, the action is limited to column A. Change the constant at the top of the code to identify the column you prefer, or change the limits to better suit your requirements. The code also checks if Cell #1 contains a formula. If that isn't what you want to fill down that condition will have to be revised.

Last, but not least, the code selects Cell#1 (the one that contained the number is over-written). That may not be the best choice. You can modify the code to select a place in your worksheet where you will continue working.